# Getting props as undefined in component returned from getStaticProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have returned json response from getStaticProps and console logged it in getStaticProps to verify correct json response. So, fetch is working fine and I am getting correct response from API.

```
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';
const Index = ({data}) => {
    console.log(data)
    return (
        <Layout>
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome to Next Application</h1>
                <h3>Users List</h3>
                {data ? 
                data.map((item, i) => {
                   return (
                   <li key={i}>{item.name}</li>
                   )
               }):
                <span>Loading...</span>
               }
                   
               
            </div>
        </Layout>
    );
}
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    return {
        props:{
            data
        } 
    }
}
export default Index;
```

Getting data as undefined in Index component.
What am I missing ?

My Output - https://ibb.co/Ns9143C
Github - https://github.com/ho-dor/next-poc

Comment: Everything looks normal and I just paste your code [overhere in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-demo-workspace-4cwx5?file=/pages/index.js)
and it works like charm :)

Comment: Please look at my output - https://ibb.co/Ns9143C

Comment: I see but as I say there is nothing wrong with this code, if something is wrong it is not here. Can you push your project to the Github or something like this so we can check it?

Comment: Github repo - https://github.com/ho-dor/next-poc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is in your custom App file, if your remove your custom App wrapper your problem will solve but if you want to keep custom app wrapper just update your `_app.js` like this:

```
import App from 'next/app';

const MyApp = ({ Component, props }) => {
    return (
        <div className="MyApp">
            <p>_app.js file</p>
            <Component {...props} />
        </div>
    );
};

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
    // calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
    const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

    return { ...appProps };
};

export default App;
```

For more info check here: [Custom App - NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)

Answer (score 3):

> `getStaticProps` (Static Generation): Fetch data at **build time**.

Maybe you could try to rebuild your app to see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

You are using custom _app component in your source code. If you're using custom _app component, you need to check if the components have static components and trigger that manually.
This will be done in custom app component itself.

If you're not using it, then you won't face any issue.

You can follow this approach I used for getInitialProps in my custom _app [here](https://github.com/karankumarshreds/SpotifyCloneReact/blob/master/pages/_app.js)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. But my problem was not the custom App component but a combination of…

1. my `getStaticPaths` was missing the path I was testing for
2. `getStaticPaths` returned `fallback: true`

With these two things together my nextjs app first built the pages on server side, but as my current path was not in the pages to be generated the `fallback` was kicking in, and this is AFAIK running on client side: My page component got parameters with `undefined` first, then getStaticProps was called, and my page component got run again, this time the parameters were filled in.

Two possible solutions:

1. allow this to happen and handle it in the page component:   `if (typeof myParam === "undefined") return "Loading..."`
2. make sure all paths are returned by `getStaticPaths` and remove the `fallback: true`. If you load an unknown path then you'll see a 404 page