# Nexjs getStaticProps / getInitialProps return undefined for a component by work if directly called from index.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying this : https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/implement-getstaticprops but I have created a new component instead of directly adding to index.js file.

While what is given in the tutorial works for me, if I try using a separate component, `getStaticProps` or `getInitialProps` returns undefined as the props.

I am adding this question as I have wasted three days to understand the root cause of it and still not able to debug it.

Answer to this question didn't worked for me: [Getting props as undefined in component returned from getStaticProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63434733/getting-props-as-undefined-in-component-returned-from-getstaticprops)

Here is my code:

`_app.js` :

```
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({Component, ctx}) => {
    const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx) : {};
    if (Object.keys(pageProps).length > 0) {
      return {pageProps};
    } else {
      return {};
    }
  };

export default MyApp
```

`globals.css`:

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu,
    Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 18px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: #0070f3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

`post.js` :

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
//import matter from 'gray-matter'

// const fs = require('fs')
// const path = require('path')

const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'posts')

export function getSortedPostsData() {
  // Get image name
  const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory)
  const allPostsData = fileNames.map(fileName => {
    const id = fileName.replace(/\.svg$/, '')
    const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, fileName)
    return {
      id,
      fullPath
    }
  })
  return allPostsData.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.date < b.date) {
      return 1
    } else {
      return -1
    }
  })
}

// console.log(getSortedPostsData())
```

`Blog.js`

```
import { getSortedPostsData } from '../lib/posts'

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const allPostsData = getSortedPostsData()
  return {
    props: {
      allPostsData
    }
  }
}

export default function Blog({ allPostsData }) {
    return (
      <div>
        <section>
        <h2>Blog</h2>
        <ul>
          {allPostsData.map(({ id, fullPath }) => (
            <li key={id}>
              {fullPath}
            </li>
          ))}
          </ul>
          </section>
        </div>
    )
  }
```

`index.js`:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Blog from '../components/Blog'

export default function Home() {
  return (
      <Blog />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getStaticProps` is [only allowed on a page](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-allowed-in-a-page).

Your `Blog` component has a `getStaticProps` but it is imported from `'../components/Blog'`. It should be in the `pages` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I get it, but I am still confused on how do I pass the static data to my blog component. @roman-mkrtchian

Comment: Got It,
I have to pass data into the blog component like
`
<Blog allPostsData={allPostsData}/>
`