# Server side prop value undefined only in the component section

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have the following where I am able to print the `data` coming from `getServerSideProps`.
But when I pass it on to the component section, the prop value `posts` is undefined. Why?

The following is under `/pages` and is inside the base index.tsx file.

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Post from '../components/Post'

const Home: NextPage = ({ posts }) => {

  // This prints undefined. This is the issue.  
  console.log(posts)

  return (
    <div>
        <Post posts={posts}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/posts/all')
  const data = await response.json()

  // this prints correctly
  console.log(data)

  return {
    props: {
      posts: data
    }
  }
};
```

Updates to show _app.tsx file

```
import Home from '../pages';

const TestApp = () => {
  return <>
      <Home />
  </>
}

export default TestApp
```

Comment: Could you show where you are passing it to the component?

Comment: @axtck Passing it inside the Post component. Essentially only looking to be able to print it for now. For this line to not be undefined. : console.log(posts)

Comment: Yes and how are you passing it to the `Home` component?

Comment: @axtck Home is not a component per se. It is inside /pages. The entire above code is inside /pages/index.tsx

Comment: if you do const Home: NextPage = (props) =>... and console.log(props), what does it return?

Comment: @tpliakas It prints empty object. {}

Comment: is there a file in pages/_app.js?

Comment: @tpliakas Yes. Updated above to show its content.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting props as undefined in component returned from getStaticProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63434733/getting-props-as-undefined-in-component-returned-from-getstaticprops)

Comment: The `_app` file needs to follow a certain syntax so that props can be passed down to pages. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the custom `_app.tsx` file or update it to accept a `Component` prop and render it as shown in the [Nextjs documentation for a Custom `App`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app).

The problem is this custom `App` is always rendering the `Home` component (with no props) so it's printing `undefined`. Then, try navigating to `/` on `localhost`. It should render the `index.tsx` file and properly invoke `getServerSideProps` and pass the result to the component as you expect.